# Chat crashes mobile chrome

Tags: bug, chat

I just recently started using stack overflow chat. I tried to access it from my iPhone with chrome web browser, but it causes it to crash sometimes. I have never had it crash this consistently on any other site. I tried to figure out how to reproduce the problem, but it is seemingly random. No specific operations or amount of time cause it, as far as I can tell

Edit: it is on iOS 7.0.4 and chrome v33.0.1750.15

Comment: Can you add the version of iOS and version of Chrome that you use?

Comment: Did you try the full site version? Any better?

Comment: I just tried it, using the "request desktop site" button. It worked fine at first, but then began rapidly jumping between the top and bottom of the page. It was un-useable unless I held my finger down.

Comment: I have this same issue. iOS 7.1 and chrome  33.0.1750.21